# Sequences that squeeze functions that the domain is all real numbers

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

I was studying about the number $e$, and, at some point, I saw in the book a particular use of a kind of squeeze theorem involving sequences and function with domain in real numbers, the book didn't proof the theorem, just assumed that is correct. The use of this theorem, in this particular case, says that

$\Big(1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}\Big)^{n}\leq\Big(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\Big)^x\leq\Big(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)^{n+1}$

Then, after using some algebra, we "can" say that if $n$ goes to $+\infty$, the sequence from the left and the right go to $e$, then the function in the middle, that the domain is $\mathbb{R}$, is squeezed and goes to $e$ as well.

For me, this result isn't obvious, once we know if we have a function $f(x)$ that the domain is $\mathbb{N}$ and the limit of this function when $n$ goes to $+\infty$ is $L$, not necessarily the limit of $f(x)$ when the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ have the same limit $L$, in fact, this $f(x)$ not necessarily has limit, it's easy to verify that and we have a bunch of counter-example.

So, my question is: is this "theorem" correct? If it's correct. Where can I find the proof? I looked in this site, in my books and over the internet and couldn't find anything. My mother language isn't english and this makes my case harder.

You can find the page of the book I used using this [here](https://ibb.co/MB9fVWR).

Comment: The key is that $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and then we use the squeeze with $x\to\infty$ which forces $n\to\infty$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the proof from the linked page. I do not know in what language it is, but, as far as I see, it is correct.
I found there no special theorem to refer but a simple observation instead.
The issue is that for each $x\ge 1$ we choose $n=n(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and obtain the expressions $f_1(n)$ and $f_2(n)$ bounding the expression $f(x)$ from both sides. Then we show that when $n$ tends to infinity,  both $f_1(n)$ and $f_2(n)$ tend to a common limit $e$. This means that for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists natural $N$ such that for each natural $n>N$ we have
$|f_1(n)-e|<\varepsilon$ and $|f_2(n)-e|<\varepsilon$. Now suppose that $x\ge N$ is any real number. Then $n=n(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor\ge N$ so $|f_1(n)-e|<\varepsilon$ and $|f_2(n)-e|<\varepsilon$. Since $f_1(n)\le f(x)\le f_2(n)$, it follows that
$|f(x)-e|<\varepsilon$, so $f(x)$ tends to $e$ when $x$ tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: Can't I say that $\sin(n\pi)\leq \sin(x\pi) \leq \sin(n\pi)$? But the $\sin(x\pi)$ diverges, once the domain that I want to evaluate are the naturals, because are the sequences that squeeze the real function (I think here is my problem to understand that).

Comment: @Curious The difference is that when $x\in (n,n+1)$ then $\sin x\pi \ne 0$, whereas $\sin (n\pi)=\sin ((n+1)\pi)=0$, 
so $\sin (n\pi)$ and $\sin ((n+1)\pi)=0$ do *not* squeeze $\sin x\pi$.

Comment: I think your answer makes sense once we considere $(1+1/x)^x$ a increasing function. But didn't we have to prove that?